# R automatic task scheduling in windows: how to use external functions

Tags: r, windows, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task in windows to run a R program ("ftp.R")

After many attempts and reading many SO literature, I found that the only way to make it work properly was writing this piece of code into a .bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
RSCRIPT ftp.R
```

Everything goes fine except wqith it, when I am trying to use functions that I have in other R programs.

For example, in the "ftp.R" program I have this pice of code:

```
  source("//BCN-01/Server/R/Main/Production/Check_Integrity.R")
```

In the "Check_Integrity.R" program I have some functions I need to use in "ftp.R".

The thing is that if I execute the .bat file manually, there is no problem, and the "ftp.R" runs perfectly. But if I run exactly the same .bat file but from the task scheduler the "ftp.R" is unable to find the external functions.

(I am running the code in a Windows Server 2012)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what was wrong:

All the paths have to be defined as absolute paths: mapped units are not valid.

Althought I already I knew that (thanks to some posts I read here in SO), I missed one path mapped into one of the functions in 'Check_Integrity.R' .

Answer (score 1):

One big difference between running a batch manually / with the scheduler is that the scheduler starts the script with system32 folder as work directory. So it might be enough to add the following line to your batch file: `CD %~dp0`.

Another point is that the scheduler runs your batch as a different user. So it is possible that you (your user account) has access to //BCN-01/Server/R/Main/Production/ while the system user the scheduler is running your script with does not. You could also try to tell the scheduler to run the script with the same user which you are logged in when running it successfully by hand.

Comment: Thks @MichaelS . I tried adding the code to the batch file but still not working. On the other hand, it's true that the scheduler is running the task with a different user than mine, but it has acces to the network as I use many other inputs and outputs and the task is able to execute them without problem (i.e `path4 <- paste0("//BCN--01/ORIGINAL DATA/Direct/",date2,"" `)
`dir.create(path4) ` )